# Codeigniter adding search term on each paginated links

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm having problems in adding additional link segments at the end of each page number. For instance, I set the config of pagination to:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url() . 'admin/employee/search/';
```

Now, each of the links may contain page numbers but I also want to include the search term.

Instead of having links like: 'mysite/admin/employee/search/1..2..3' on paginated numbers,

I want to have like this: 'mysite/admin/employee/search/mysearchterm/1..2..3'.

How would I do it?

Comment: do not use segment to provide your search term, use get instead & add it as a query string to the pagination links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($this->uri->segment(3)){
    $keyword = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
else if($this->input->get('keyword')){
    $keyword = $this->input->get('keyword');
}
$config['base_url']         = base_url().'home/paginate_search/'.$keyword.'/page/';
```